# Verilog - Iterating Over All Cases In Testbench

Tags: verilog, signal, test

In coursework, we are creating multiple circuits and explicitly testing every single case in Verilog.  The way that we have been writing test benches so far is the following:

```
initial begin
    $monitor("%d %d %d %d | %d  %d", A, B, C, D, F1, F2);
    A=0;B=0;C=0;D=0;#10;
    A=0;B=0;C=0;D=1;#10;
    A=0;B=0;C=1;D=0;#10;
    A=0;B=0;C=1;D=1;#10;
    A=0;B=1;C=0;D=0;#10;
    A=0;B=1;C=0;D=1;#10;
    A=0;B=1;C=1;D=0;#10;
    A=0;B=1;C=1;D=1;#10;
    A=1;B=0;C=0;D=0;#10;
    A=1;B=0;C=0;D=1;#10;
    A=1;B=0;C=1;D=0;#10;
    A=1;B=0;C=1;D=1;#10;
    A=1;B=1;C=0;D=0;#10;
    A=1;B=1;C=0;D=1;#10;
    A=1;B=1;C=1;D=0;#10;
    A=1;B=1;C=1;D=1;#10;
end
```

I feel like there has to be a better way to iterate over every state of the input and view the output.  Does anyone know of a way to have a test bench do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you treat the inputs as a bus, you can add 1 to them until they overflow. Something like this works ([online simulation](http://www.iverilog.com/index.php?public_code=2gwGUs)):

```
initial begin
  $monitor("%d %d %d %d", A, B, C, D);
  {A,B,C,D} = 4'b0000;
end 
always begin
  #10;
  {A,B,C,D} = {A,B,C,D} + 4'b1;
  if (&{A,B,C,D}) begin
    #10;
    $finish;
  end
end
```